# Relations - anty symmetric, reflexive and transitive?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So I'm trying to answer this question :
Show that if a relation $S= f(x,y)$ that belongs to $N  : x$ is the power of $y$ , is a partial order, is it a total relation ? justify.

Note: this is a rough translation because it was in another language but I believe that is how you write it in English. what I meant by partial order is that it needs to be reflexive, anti-symmetric and transitive.

So first of all I don't know how that is a relation of partial order and second how do I see if it is of a total relation?

Comment: I am assuming the relation you described at firs is $x<y$ if and only if $x^n=y$ for some integer $n$. You want to know if a subset of this relation is a partial order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean the relation $$x \sim y :\Leftrightarrow x \text { is a power of } y$$ To show, that this relation is a partial order you need to show the following:

- $\sim$ is reflexiv: For each $x\in\mathbb N$ is true, that $x$ is a power of $x$.
- $\sim$ is antisymmetric: If $x$ is a power of $y$ and $y$ is a power of $x$, then $x=y$.
- $\sim$ is transitive: If $x$ is a power of $y$ and $y$ is a power of $z$, then $x$ is a power of $z$.

The proofs for each of the above points are left to you...